# Connect to Ignite server with public and private ip

Tags: ignite

I tried to connect my Ignite client `A` (running in Eclipse IDE) to a remote Ignite server `B` running in a different network (OpenStack VM). `B` has a public IP ("floating IP"): like `193.224.x.x` and a private IP: `192.168.0.4` (not visible from `A`). 
In `A`, I set the public IP of `B` to connect to in Java (like: `IgniteConfiguration < TcpDiscoverySpi.setIpFinder < TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder < setAddresses(Arrays.asList("193.224.x.x")`). Port `47500` (and some others for Ignite) are open on `B` to everyone.
Then I start the client I get exception after while:

```
SEVERE: Failed to reinitialize local partitions (preloading will be stopped): GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=6, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=4a4a9c63-b3e6-4191-a966-6fe86071c7d5, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.100], sockAddrs=[/192.168.1.100:0, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0], discPort=0, order=6, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1530529560836, loc=true, ver=2.5.0#20180523-sha1:86e110c7, isClient=true], topVer=6, nodeId8=4a4a9c63, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1530529560973], nodeId=4a4a9c63, evt=NODE_JOINED]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to send message (node may have left the grid or TCP connection cannot be established due to firewall issues) [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=d5828cee-0bbb-45e8-ba55-c34c1e68f165, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1, 192.168.0.4], sockAddrs=[/192.168.0.4:47500, /172.17.0.1:47500, 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1530529560939, loc=false, ver=2.5.0#20180523-sha1:86e110c7, isClient=false], topic=TOPIC_CACHE, msg=GridDhtPartitionsSingleMessage [parts=null, partCntrs=null, partSizes=null, partHistCntrs=null, err=null, client=true, compress=true, finishMsg=null, super=GridDhtPartitionsAbstractMessage [exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=6, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=4a4a9c63-b3e6-4191-a966-6fe86071c7d5, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.100], sockAddrs=[/192.168.1.100:0, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0], discPort=0, order=6, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1530529560836, loc=true, ver=2.5.0#20180523-sha1:86e110c7, isClient=true], topVer=6, nodeId8=4a4a9c63, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1530529560973], nodeId=4a4a9c63, evt=NODE_JOINED], lastVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=0, order=1530529560661, nodeOrder=0], super=GridCacheMessage [msgId=1, depInfo=null, err=null, skipPrepare=false]]], policy=2]
```

I see signs about that the client is actually connected to the server for a moment (Topology snapshot `[ver=6, servers=1, clients=1, CPUs=8,`) but after that it is disconnected (or something happens). From the exception it seems (I feel like) the client wants to connect to `sockAddrs=[/192.168.0.4:47500...`, which fails, instead of `193.224.x.x:47500`.

I tried what I found to let `B` to know its external IP,
in config file, but neither worked:

```
<property name="addressResolver">
    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.BasicAddressResolver">
        <constructor-arg>
            <map>
                <entry key="192.168.0.4" value="193.224.x.x">
```

nor

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
    <property name="localAddress" value="193.224.x.x"/>
```

nor

```
<property name="discoverySpi">
     <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
         <property name="localAddress" value="193.224.x.x"/>
```

I have no more idea how to fix it. Ignite docs are very brief regarding to this clustering config.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Discovery works for you but Communication fails.

You can try supplying your own `TcpCommunicationSpi` to `IgniteConfiguration`, setting `localAddress` on it to `193.224.x.x` on server node. However this will likely cause all node-to-node traffic to travel on external network.

You can also try to set localAddress to `193.224.x.x` (or other external address) on node A to make sure it doesn't bind to *its own* `192.168.x.x` that isn't shared with B. While leaving configuration on B intact.

Comment: I'll double check the communication port again. I tried TcpCommunicationSpi.locaAddress on server-side, didn't work.

Comment: Port 47100 is open on server node. Also, opened UDP. No success.

Comment: @AkosHajnal If you have any software based firewall configured on the servers, please disable it and try again. If it works, then you can try re-enabling it and opening up the necessary ports.

Comment: @AkosHajnal it is usually assumed that all Ignite nodes are in the same network. So there's no much support for hairy configurations.

Comment: Alamar, Dimitriy thank you for your comments. I use OpenStack's "firewall" (rules), all TCP ports opened. I do some more investigation and coming back if any news.

Comment: I had some problems with Eclipse compiler and peerclassloading and lambdas, even with Eclipse Photon. IntelliJ works. But the problem still remains. I don't know why the server B does not report its public IP in this list: addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 172.17.0.1, 192.168.0.4] even if I set addressresolver. Do I put into a wrong place in the configuration file? Without that A cannot connect again to B (after the initial connection timeouts), I guess.

Comment: @AkosHajnal are we talking about Discovery or Communication here?
Maybe the node doesn't report its address because it doesn't consider being in the same subnet? I will have to check that.

Comment: @Alamar Good question, it is unclear for me. I guess discovery is to find other nodes in the topology, communication is to pass data. So both are needed  to connect A and B. A and B are in different subnets. That is why I force this public IP stuff.

Comment: It seems now it works. I used Ignite 2.5.0 and tried to run ML example: LinearRegressionLSQRTrainerWithNormalizationExample.

Comment: I had to upload to B example binaries (into IGNITE_HOME/libs/): arpack_combined_all-0.1.jar, ignite-examples-2.5.0.jar.
(The latter has to be built manually, the former is somewhere in ~/.m2/).

The important thing was to configure "communicationSpi" and set both localAddress and addressResolver.

Comment: Like this: ` <property name="communicationSpi">
             <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
                <property name="localAddress" value="192.168.x.x"/>
         <property name="addressResolver">
           <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.BasicAddressResolver">
           <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key="192.168.x.x" value="193.224.x.x"/>
     </map>
    </constructor-arg>
   </bean>
      </property>
             </bean>
         </property>`